# firebase-app.js not loading shows net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 (OK)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a website with a booking form which stores the data in firestore. But I am getting error on loading firebase. The error is given below.

> GET http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-app.js
> net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 (OK)

There are several more errors like:

> index.ts:79 TypeError: Cannot read property 'INTERNAL' of undefined
> at index.ts:41
> at index.ts:79
> at firebase-analytics.js:1
> at firebase-analytics.js:1 (anonymous) @ index.ts:79 (anonymous) @ firebase-analytics.js:1 (anonymous) @ firebase-analytics.js:1
> index.ts:79 Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-analytics.js -
> be sure to load firebase-app.js first.
> at index.ts:79
> at firebase-analytics.js:1
> at firebase-analytics.js:1 (anonymous) @ index.ts:79 (anonymous) @ firebase-analytics.js:1 (anonymous) @ firebase-analytics.js:1
> init.js:1 Uncaught Error: hosting/init-error: Firebase SDK not
> detected. You must include it before /__/firebase/init.js
> at init.js:1 (anonymous) @ init.js:1 index.ts:38 TypeError: Cannot read property 'SDK_VERSION' of undefined
> at version.ts:21
> at index.ts:38
> at firebase-firestore.js:1
> at firebase-firestore.js:1 (anonymous) @ index.ts:38 (anonymous) @ firebase-firestore.js:1 (anonymous) @ firebase-firestore.js:1
> index.ts:38 Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-firestore.js -
> be sure to load firebase-app.js first.
> at index.ts:38
> at firebase-firestore.js:1
> at firebase-firestore.js:1

I am initializing firebase with these lines:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="/__/firebase/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

What is the reason of it and how can I solve it?
Thanks for any kind of help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you just need to use the same version across all libraries.  Mixing v7.14.5 with v8.2.1 is going to cause problems.

Second, this is a [known firebase-tools issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3052) and they are saying that updating to 8.2.3 resolves it.  So my recommendation is to do the following:

1. Open a cmd or console window and update firebase-tools to the latest version:

```
firebase i -g firebase-tools
```

2. Update the version number of all of your scripts to 8.2.3.

Comment: No it still shows the same error... Nothing is working. I am out of mind

Comment: Turns out it's a known issue in firebase-tools and updating the version number fixes it.  Updated my answer above.